# Showing a function is injective in a disk

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Please help me prove that if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is analytic in $D_r=\{z:|z|<r\}$ and $r|a_1|>\sum_{n=2}^\infty n|a_n|r^n$, then $f$ is an injective function in $D_r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, $|z_1|, |z_2| < r$, then

$$
0 = |f(z_1) - f(z_2)| = |\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n(z_1^n - z_2^n)| = |z_1 - z_2||\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}z_1^kz_2^{n - 1 - k}| \\
\geq |z_1 - z_2|(|a_1| - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty |a_n|\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}|z_1|^k|z_2|^{n - 1 - k}) = |z_1 - z_2|(|a_1| - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty n|a_n|r^{n - 1}),
$$

since $|a_1| - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty n|a_n|r^{n - 1} > 0$, so we have $|z_1 - z_2| = 0$, i.e. $z_1 = z_2$. Hence $f$ is injective.