# Prove that a function of the form $f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n,$ with the condition $\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n,$$ be an analytic function on the open unit disc $D$ around $0$ with $a_1 \neq 0$. Suppose that $$\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|.$$ Then prove that $f$ is one-one on $D$.

The given condition $\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|$ provides,

$$|f'(z)|=|\sum_{n \geq 1} na_n z^{n-1}|>0$$ on the boundary $\partial D=\{z \in \Bbb C : |z|=1\}$. How can I proceed now? If we are able to show $|f'(z)|>0$ for all $z \in D$, is it enough to say $f$ is one-one on $D$ ?

The converse is clear for me that 'If $f$ is a non-constant injective analytic function on an open set $U \subseteq \Bbb C$, then $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in U$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617245/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%20%5Cgeq%202%7D%5Cleft%7Cn%20a_n%5Cright%7C%3C%5Cleft%7Ca_1%5Cright%7C%24)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426373/42969.